# Why can not read and write stream in thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I want to process the http request in thread, the code as follow where the problem is that OutputStream (as noted in codes) can not be writen. When I put this process in main thread, it's no problem. Can you give me any advice?

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
            var server = new HttpServer();
            try
            {
                server.EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(127.0.0.0, 80); //set webServer para
                server.Start(); //start webServer
                server.RequestReceived += server_RequestReceived; //register the event
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return;
            }
       }
       private void server_RequestReceived(object sender, HttpRequestEventArgs e)
       {
           var dataProcess = new Action<HttpRequestEventArgs>(DataProcess);
           Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(dataProcess,e); //start thread
       }
       private void DataProcess(HttpRequestEventArgs e)
       {
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");
           string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
           using (var writer = new StreamWriter(e.Response.OutputStream)) //**Cannot write stream**
           {
               writer.Write(text);
           }
           sr.Close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you write the stream?  Is there an exception?  What's the message, if so?  What's the unexpected behavior, if not?

Comment: It is quite possible that the `e.Response.OutputStream` is going out of scope and being disposed.

Comment: @phoog: the message is "can not access a closed stream".

Comment: @EbenRoux: I think so, but i do not konw how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your request is being close before the new thread runs. What you can do is to execute the whole request in the new thread. Something like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        var start = new Action<HttpRequestEventArgs>(Start);
        Dispatcher.start(start,e); //start thread
   }

   private void Start(HttpRequestEventArgs e)
   {
        var server = new HttpServer();
        server.EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(127.0.0.0, 80); //set webServer para
        server.Start(); //start webServe
        server.RequestReceived += server_RequestReceived; //register the event
   }

   private void server_RequestReceived(object sender, HttpRequestEventArgs e)
   {
       StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");
       string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
       using (var writer = new StreamWriter(e.Response.OutputStream)) //**Cannot write stream**
       {
           writer.Write(text);
       }
       sr.Close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likley `e.Response.OutputStream` is write-only stream which contains response received from the server.

Depending on what you want to do you may either write to request stream or read from OutputStream.

Note: you are using some custom classes, so suggestion is based purely on method names.